# Can I put a switch on a light after a Mechanical Timer?

Tags: electrical, wiring

Ok, I'm running my "line" to a mechanical timer that controls 2 lights. Can I hook up a wire to the timers "line" (for a hot) and use that to be the hot for a switch, then run another wire from switch back to the timers "load" where the lights switch leg is (currently located) and be ok?

Comment: Sounds like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/).  You're describing methods to do a thing (”after the timer” what is that anyway?, then describing a wiring method). But we have no idea what your objective is, so couldn't speculate if that method will do anything you would want. Hint: you are probably not the first person with this problem.

Comment: What do you want the switch to do? Turn the light in question on and off independent of the timer? Override the timer, for one light or both?  Allow either one light or both lights to be on when the timer turns them on?

Comment: Is this a code question or a physics question?

Comment: Perhaps he should have used the word "may" instead of "can." Do you think it's possible to infer the meaning from context?

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can. It ought to work fine. A switch is a switch no matter where you put it.